# React-Native TypeORM: Cyclic dependency "t" Android Release build

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native, typeorm, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am using TypeORM in a React-Native app in which I need SQLite storage. It works really well, except for a bug that I've been struggling with all week.

My scheme contains several objects that are related to one another with one-to-may, many-to-one, and many-to-many relations. Sometimes, one entity has multiple many-to-many relations.

I am developing this app mainly on Android, and in debug mode it works perfect. Saving and reading data goes smooth, It does exactly what I expect. In release mode, however, I keep on getting a very cryptic error message:

```
[Error: Cyclic dependency: "t"]
```

TypeORM usually does a good job in telling you what's wrong. Here, however, it gives me no info whatsoever about where I made a mistake, on what entity. Also, googling this error message, or looking it up on their website, gives me no result.

**Question:** I have been struggling with this all week without any results. Can anyone tell me:

- What does this message mean?
- Is this something I did wrong in my code, or a bug in TypeORM?
- If I'm causing this: How did I, and how can I solve it?
- Why does it only appear in android release mode, and does it work completely fine in Android debug mode?

Any help would be highly appreciated.